# How to limit a sizer within a certain space? (wxWidgets)

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, sizer

I'm using a sizer to place the buttons in a grid:

[image]

However, I don't want the sizer to use all the space in the window, but just a small area, like the following (in the white area):

[image]

Is this possible to achieve? And if yes, how?
*Please know that I'm VERY new to wxWidgets.*

By the way, here's the code behind the frame:

```
Main::Main() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "IKE Calculator", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(500, 650), wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wxMAXIMIZE_BOX & ~wxRESIZE_BORDER)
{
    int w = 3, h = 3;

    NumBtn = new wxButton*[w*h];
    NumSizer = new wxGridSizer(w, h, 0, 0);

    //Populate sizer
    int cycle = 1;
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            int current = (y * w + x);
            NumBtn[current] = new wxButton(this, BUTTON_NUM + current, std::to_string(cycle));
            NumSizer->Add(NumBtn[current], 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL);

            cycle++;
        }
    }

    this->SetSizer(NumSizer);
    NumSizer->Layout();
}

Main::~Main()
{
    delete[] NumBtn;
}
```

Comment: can you post you code? In particular - do you have any other control, and how do you add buttons to a sizer?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit this post

Comment: 2 solutions: you can try to give the frame the initial size or you can override `DoGetBestSize()` and return the minimal size for the button. But generally speaking - why do you need that? Even if you achieve what you want, when user resizes the frame controls will resize with it. That's the whole idea of the sizers. You can also try to use just `wxEXPAND` or just use `0` as last parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Sizers are used to position children of a window and they use the entire window client area (i.e. everything inside it) for this. This doesn't mean that you can't position your buttons in the way you want to do it, of course, it just means that you have to do it in the right way:

1. Either you can create a child window which takes just the area you want it to occupy and then you create your buttons as its children and associate the sizer with this window. This, of course, assumes you can position this window correctly, but windows have `SetSize()` method, so in principle this could be done. But setting sizers manually is not the right thing to do and you risk running into a [common issue](https://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/faq/common/#tlwchildresize) with positioning the only child of a window, so it's better to do it in another way.
2. This other way is to use "spacers", which are sizer elements that take "space", without doing anything else, to occupy the unused parts of the window. For example, in this case you could create a vertical box sizer (`wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL)`) containing a spacer of the given height (the top area) and a horizontal box sizer containing a spacer corresponding to the left gap and your current sizer.

Note that a layout such as what you want to create is rather unusual, typically you don't need to just leave arbitrarily-sized parts of the window empty. So you wouldn't do something like this often, but if you really want to, you can do it, of course.

Comment: Before I created this post I tried creating a wxPanel inside the frame, and then setting the wxGridSizer to the panel. The panel was created successfully, however, the buttons were not.

Comment: The fact is that I’m trying to create a calculator, similar to the Windows default one. As with every digital calculator, there are 9 big buttons with numbers from 1 to 9, positioned in a grid, and then other smaller buttons with operations like multiplication, division etc. on the side. What you saw was my attempt in creating the 9 buttons, is this the approach I’m supposed to use to achieve my goal, or do you suggest trying something else, for example placing the buttons manually?

Comment: For the calculator you just want borders around the buttons that can be easily added to any sizer item, so you probably don't need any spacers at all. Just break down your desired layout in the rectangular boxes, from top to bottom, and create sizers for each of them.

Comment: What do you mean with rectangular boxes? Windows, panels? Also, which type of sizer should I use (wxGridSizer, wxFlexGridSizer, wxBoxSizer etc.)?

Comment: "Rectangular boxes" == `wxBoxSizer`

Comment: So if I want the 9 buttons placed in a grid I need to place them manually if I use wxBoxSixer?

Comment: No, you can use `wxGridSizer` for placing these buttons inside the inner most box, of course. But mostly things are not organized in regular grids, so you use `wxBoxSizer` to divide them in rectangular sections, and lay out each of them -- by subdividing it in even smaller rectangles if necessary.

Comment: So you mean inserting a wxGridSizer inside a wxBoxSizer? Could you give me an example of how you'd code this? Because I'm having some trouble understanding (I'm new with this framework)

Comment: The idea is exactly to nest sizers into each other, yes. This is what I meant by "doing it from top to bottom".